# How to add , between 00, 000, 11, 111 etc in Ruby

Tags: ruby, gsub

I have a string input and I'd like insert `,` between `00` and `11` like the following example.

```
input1 = '00011010100011101'
desired_result1 = '0,0,01,101010,0,01,1,101'

input2 = '11010111101010000001011'
desired_result2 = '1,10101,1,1,101010,0,0,0,0,0101,1'
```

I tried the following but it doesn't give me what I want.

```
input1.gsub(/00/,'0,0').gsub(/11/,'1,1')
=> "0,001,101010,001,1101"
```

I appreciate any inputs.

**Note** Answers to this question may be later silently used [here](https://github.com/shinokada/ioi-jp/blob/master/2013/2013-ho/lib/illumination.rb) without credits.

Comment: shin, your questions are improving! +1  The examples with desired results help a lot.

Answer (score 5):

One way of doing it is by using a lookbehind (`(?<=...)`). This is a zero-width assertion that isn't captured, so you can match on a 1 that is preceeded by a 1, or a 0 preceeded by 0:

```
input.gsub(/(?<=1)1|(?<=0)0/, ',\0')
```

`\0` is the matched string, i.e. a `1` or `0`, but not the `1` or `0` preceding it.

[Here is a good guide on lookahead and lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Answer (score 3):

```
input.gsub(/(00+|11+)/) { |m| m.split(//).join(',') }
# => "0,0,01,101010,0,01,1,101"
```

Comment: Improves readability and does not send `split` to arrays with only one element.

Answer (score 3):

Look, ma, no gsub, no regex!

```
def insert_commas(str)
  ([str[0]] + str.chars.each_cons(2).map { |a,b| a==b ? ','+b : b }).join('')
end

insert_commas('00011010100011101')
  #=> "0,0,01,101010,0,01,1,101"
insert_commas('11010111101010000001011')
  #=> "1,10101,1,1,101010,0,0,0,0,0101,1"
```

Answer (score 2):

Generaling @spickermann's solution:

```
input1.gsub(/(.)\1+/) { |m| m.split('').join(',') }
# => "0,0,01,101010,0,01,1,101"
```